# Combining Multiple Query Results from Different Tables into one query result table

Tags: sql, oracle

How would I go about combining many query results, all from different tables, into one resulting table?

```
SELECT LEAST( (HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) / AVG(HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) OVER (),
              1
            ) as res
FROM EDUCATIONPROFILE
ORDER BY cid ASC
```

```
SELECT LEAST( (EMPLOYED -  UNEMPLOYED) / AVG(EMPLOYED - UNEMPLOYED) OVER (),
              1
            ) as res
FROM ECONOMICPROFILE
ORDER BY cid ASC
```

```
SELECT ((MAXTEMP + MINTEMP)/ 2)/ (SELECT MAX((MAXTEMP + MINTEMP)/ 2) FROM CLIMATEPROFILE) FROM CLIMATEPROFILE ORDER BY cid ASC
```

```
SELECT (crimecount) / (SELECT MAX(CRIMECOUNT)  FROM CRIMECOUNTS) FROM CRIMECOUNTS ORDER BY cid ASC
```

The goal being one query result (table) with different columns each having one of the respective queries result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all appear to have *cid*, simply `JOIN` each resultset:

```
SELECT educ.cid, educ.educ_res, econ.econ_res, clim.climate_res, crime.crime_res
FROM
  (SELECT LEAST((HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) / 
                 AVG(HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) OVER (), 1) AS educ_res
   FROM EDUCATIONPROFILE
  ) educ

INNER JOIN
  (SELECT LEAST((EMPLOYED -  UNEMPLOYED) / 
                AVG(EMPLOYED - UNEMPLOYED) OVER (), 1) AS econ_res
   FROM ECONOMICPROFILE
  ) econ
ON educ.cid = econ.cid

INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT ((MAXTEMP + MINTEMP)/ 2)/ 
           (SELECT MAX((MAXTEMP + MINTEMP)/ 2) FROM CLIMATEPROFILE) AS climate_res
   FROM CLIMATEPROFILE
  ) clim
ON clim.cid = educ.cid

INNER JOIN
  (SELECT (crimecount) / (SELECT MAX(CRIMECOUNT)  FROM CRIMECOUNTS) AS crime_res
   FROM CRIMECOUNTS
  ) crime
ON crime.cid = educ.cid

ORDER BY educ.cid
```

Alternatively with CTEs:

```
WITH educ AS
  (SELECT LEAST((HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) / 
                 AVG(HSDIPLOMA + BACHELORDEGREE) OVER (), 1) AS educ_res
   FROM EDUCATIONPROFILE
  ), 
     econ AS 
  (SELECT LEAST((EMPLOYED -  UNEMPLOYED) / 
                AVG(EMPLOYED - UNEMPLOYED) OVER (), 1) AS econ_res
   FROM ECONOMICPROFILE
  ), 
     clim AS
  (SELECT ((MAXTEMP + MINTEMP)/ 2)/ 
           (SELECT MAX((MAXTEMP + MINTEMP)/ 2) FROM CLIMATEPROFILE) AS climate_res
   FROM CLIMATEPROFILE
  ), 
     crime AS
  (SELECT (crimecount) / (SELECT MAX(CRIMECOUNT)  FROM CRIMECOUNTS) AS crime_res
   FROM CRIMECOUNTS
  ) 

SELECT educ.cid, educ.educ_res, econ.econ_res, clim.climate_res, crime.crime_res
FROM educ
INNER JOIN econ 
    ON educ.cid = econ.cid
INNER JOIN clim
    ON clim.cid = educ.cid
INNER JOIN crim
    ON crime.cid = educ.cid
ORDER BY educ.cid
```